# How to load data from Databricks DBFS using Auto Loader

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

Hi It seems I could not load data correctly from DBFS is Databricks using Auto loader, at least it is not displaying the data -- 'Query returned no results'. Any help is welcome!

[image]

Comment: yes @DileeprajnarayanThumula

Answer (score 0):

I just should locate to the mnt folder and save and read my data from there.

Changing the path to '/mnt/data-lake/data/autoloader-test/' for exmaple, worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `/dbfs` from your paths - this path is used for local file access, not for distributed access.

P.S. Also, don't put the checkpoint & schema evolution folders into subfolders of your landing zone.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentioned , `/dbfs` is your driver node local file . You can use following code.

```
bronzeDF  = (spark.readStream
.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
.option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", var_schema_location)
.load(var_data_location) #Your dbfs location 
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", var_checkpoint_location)
.option("mergeSchema", "true")
.trigger(once=True)
.table(raw_logs_table_name)
.awaitTermination())

bronzeDF = spark.table(var_raw_log_table)
```